# Content links issue in jQuery script

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-plugins, hyperlink

Could someone solve an issue with links in a [demo](http://wegraphics.net/demo/avenir/).

The 'more info »' link on the home page isn't clickable.

It's directed to the about section, but it doesn't work.

The navigation and section content links are coded as:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    /* How to Handle Hashtags */
    jQuery(window).hashchange(function(){
        var hash = location.hash;
        jQuery('a[href='+hash+']').trigger('click');
    });

    /* Main Navigation Clicks */
    jQuery('.main-nav ul li a').click(function() {
        var link = jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(1);

        if ( !jQuery('section.content.show, section#' + link).is(':animated') ) {
            jQuery('.main-nav ul li a').removeClass('active'); //remove active
            jQuery('section.content.show').addClass('show').animate({'opacity' : 0}, {queue: false, duration: 1000,
                complete: function() {
                    jQuery('a[href="#'+link+'"]').addClass('active'); // add active
                    jQuery('section#' + link).addClass('show').animate({'opacity' : 1}, {queue: false, duration: 1000});    
                }
            });
        }
    });

});

.show{display: block;}
.hide{opacity: 0;}
```

What is missing in the script for the links to work properly?

Also the fading transition of the background images seem to be flickering in Safari.

```
div.mc-image {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; 
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;

    /*If you are using horizontal slide transitions, use the following CSS:
    -webkit-transition: left 1s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: left 1s ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: left 1s ease-in-out; 
    transition: left 1s ease-in-out;*/

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hidden sections aren't really hidden. You've just set the opacity on them to 0. They're still there, so when you click on the "More Info" link, you're actually clicking on the "Follow our updates on Twitter" link.

Try changing your `.hide` class to `display: none;` instead of `opacity: 0;`. Since you're using jQuery, just use [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) instead of manually messing with the opacity. This will probably also solve your flickering issue in Safari.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/XMACH/

Comment: The link is clickable but now the navigation links don't work either.

Comment: @Martijn: Take a look at the jsFiddle I just put in the answer. You will no longer use opacity. When you click on a link, you'll do something similar to the jsFiddle...do a fadeOut() followed by a fadeIn() on the section that should be shown.